# Sed reg expression with an AND operator, does not work, why not?

Tags: regex, sed, xml-parsing

```
<ServerCluster CloneSeparatorChange="false" GetDWLMTable="false" IgnoreAffinityRequests="true" LoadBalance="Round Robin" Name="Penguin-CL-Nest-s1" ServerIOTimeoutRetry="-1">
```

What I trying to do is a find and replace, where the string matches IgnoreAffinityRequests="true" AND Penguin-CL-Nest-s1 or s2, then when matched the string true should be replaced with false.

```
enterIgnoreAffinityRequests="true"
Name="Penguin-CL-Nest-s1"
Name="Penguin-CL-Nest-s2"
```

Here is the command I'm using on SLES11.3

```
sed -i -r -e '/IgnoreAffinityRequests="true"/{;/Name="Penguin-CL-Nest-\w\d"/s/IgnoreAffinityRequests="true"/IgnoreAffinityRequests="false"/;}' example1
```

Its does work with no regexp, any help gratefully appreciated, thanks.

```
sed -i -e '/IgnoreAffinityRequests="true"/{;/Name="Penguin-CL-Nest-s1"/s/IgnoreAffinityRequests="true"/IgnoreAffinityRequests="false"/;}' example1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing XML with sed is not a good idea because whitespaces in unexpected places or reordered attributes -- that no one who works with XML expects to be a problem -- can break your script. XML is not a line-based format, sed is a line-based tool, so the two don't go well together.

Instead, I advise you to use a tool that parses and edits XML properly, such as `xmlstarlet`. In this case:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//ServerCluster[(@Name="Penguin-CL-Nest-s1" or @Name="Penguin-CL-Nest-s2") and @IgnoreAffinityRequests="true"]/@IgnoreAffinityRequests' -v 'false'
```

The key part of this is the XPath after `-u`, where

- `//ServerCluster` is a `ServerCluster` node anywhere in the document,
- `//ServerCluster[condition]/@IgnoreAffinityRequests` is the `IgnoreAffinityRequests` attribute of a `ServerCluster` node anywhere in the document that fulfills the `condition`, and
- the condition `(@Name="Penguin-CL-Nest-s1" or @Name="Penguin-CL-Nest-s2") and @IgnoreAffinityRequests="true"` is true if the `Name` and `IgnoreAffinityRequests` attribute of the `ServerCluster` node fulfill it.

As such, the `xmlstarlet` command will update all entities that match this (i.e., the `IgnoreAffinityRequests` attributes of `ServerClusterNodes` whose `IgnoreAffinityRequests` attribute is currently true and whose `Name` attribute is either `Penguin-CL-Nest-s1` or `Penguin-CL-Nest-s2`) with the value `false`.

Comment: Then you might use something like `sed '/Name="Penguin-CL-Nest-s[12]/ s/IgnoreAffinityRequests="true"/IgnoreAffinityRequests="false"/'`, which will do the substitution `s/IgnoreAffinityRequests="true"/IgnoreAffinityRequests="false"/` in lines that match `/Name="Penguin-CL-Nest-s[12]/`. The basic form is `/pattern/ command`, in which `command` will be executed if the pattern space (the line, or the result of editing the line in previous commands) matches `pattern`.